# Run code exactly at specific time with zero seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code,

```
def test():
    print("Test")
```

I want to run this code exactly at 09:00:00 am and loop it to run it after each 60 seconds till 16:00:00 pm.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can do this easily with `cron`.

Comment: And whichever system you're on, you can do this with the `schedule` module.  https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @TimRoberts I am on Mac and I want to achieve it with using Python code

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer  (EDIT:  look at the first comment under this answer for improvements which can be made):

---

This can be done using only Python, if you import the Tkinter and datetime modules.  I wouldn't recommend running this particular program for as long as in your question, but it does work as a proof of concept.

```
# Runs:
# Starting at the specified start time,
# Every specified interval (in seconds) until the specified end time,
# With precision equal to precisionInterval (i.e. how often does the function check what time it is)

# The first two parameters are strings of the form 'hh:mm:ss'
# The third parameter is an integer representing seconds
# The fourth parameter is an integer representing milliseconds

# The last parameter should not be provided by the user.

import tkinter as tk
import datetime

window = tk.Tk()

def timerFunction(fromStartTime, untilEndTime, repeatEveryThisManySeconds, precisionInterval, untilNextTime=0):
    functionParameters = [fromStartTime, untilEndTime, repeatEveryThisManySeconds, precisionInterval, untilNextTime]

    # The first 11 characters of datetime.datetime.now() are the year, month and day,
    # separated by hyphens and followed by a space.  Remove these characters as they are not relevant.

    # The next 8 characters are the hour, minute and second, separated by colons.  After this are a
    # decimal point and milliseconds.  Remove these final characters too.

    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())[11:19]

    # First, check whether it is the start time yet.  If it is at or after the start time, start
    # printing output.  Because of the way the time is formatted, strings can be compared directly
    # without converting to numbers first.

    if (currentTime >= fromStartTime):
        if (untilNextTime <= 0):
            # Reset the countdown every time output is printed
            print("Test:  it is now " + currentTime)
            functionParameters[4] = repeatEveryThisManySeconds*1000
        else:
            functionParameters[4] -= precisionInterval

    if (currentTime >= untilEndTime):
        # Avoid useless looping after the deadline
        return

    window.after(precisionInterval, lambda: timerFunction(*functionParameters))


timerFunction('15:45:00', '15:50:00', 1, 100)
```

For some reason, it occasionally skips a second, and I don't know why this would be since the update rate is set to 0.1 seconds.

Comment: This is not a particularly good solution.  Tkinter is a totally unnecessary and expensive module for this task.  A loop with `time.sleep` will do just as well.  And you should be using timestamps instead of comparing strings.